# hasttable with custom struct key

Tags: c, hashtable

I'm trying to implement hashtable for a customly defined struct as a key.
I got this example as a starting point:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/hash_table_program_in_c.htm

Here is my custom struct for a key:

```
typedef struct vector3struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
} Vector3;
```

Here is the hashtable item:

```
typedef struct datatitemstruct
{
    Vector3 *key;
    int data;
} DataItem;
```

And the hashtable declaration looks like this:

```
DataItem *hashArray[HASH_ARRAY_SIZE];
```

Is there some good way to implement a GetHashKey function for my Vector3 so I can iterate over the items in the array to search for the item I need?

And if there is improvements available - please tell.

Comment: There are many ways to hash. The best ones utilize domain knowledge about the ranges of the participating scalars. -- Aside: _hash table_ vs _iterate_ - maybe you don't have the ideal data type for what you need to do.

Comment: The point of a hashtable and a hash function is that you don't need to iterate over a set to look for an item. However, hash table items can have collisions (meaning different items can have the same key), and you have to decide how you want to handle these cases (replace, ignore, add to a list...).
In your case, GetHashKey shoud just be a function that combines x, y and z from Vector3 and returns a number between 0 and `HASH_ARRAY_SIZE - 1` ( operator `%` might help here). What operation is more efficient will depend of the values you end up having as keys once the program runs.

Comment: @JulienThierry I was thinking of giving the user ability to check if the key exists or not - that's why I mentioned iteration. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Since you have a hash table, if the key (or rather the vector) exists in the hash table, the only location it could be located at is `GetHashKey(vect)`. So, checking if the vector is in the table should at most be `hashArray[GetHashKey(vect)] != NULL && hashArray[GetHashKey(vect)]->key->x == vect->x` (and also testing `y` and `z`).
You shouldn't need to iterate. If your vector is at another position in your hash table then you've misimplemented something.

Comment: @JulienThierry oh, right! Thanks!

Comment: _Hash_ implies non-recoverable plain text.  Useful for storing passwords, but do not typically need a _key_ word.   Encrypted content on the other hand _is_ recoverable with a key word.

Comment: Why a pointer in `Vector3 *key`? To make a passable hash function, the entire key must be used.

Comment: @JulienThierry: that's not correct; hash tables usually risk collisions, so a key might not be at the initially hashed-to bucket.  The data structures presented in the question imply intent to use open addressing aka closed hashing, and "iterating" suggests intent to use "linear probing".  That's all legitimate.

Comment: @Neil: it's a little more complicated than that: if - for some reason - the program knows each `Vector3` object that a `DataItem` might point to has a distinct set of coordinates, then you could hash the `Vector3*`.  For a general solution though, you're right that you'd want the hash function to use the coordinates and *not* the pointer, but that doesn't mean there's a problem having using `DataItem` as is - OP just needs to dereference the pointers and incorporate the coordinates in the hash value.

Comment: @ryyker: what's meant by a hash [value] is quite different (from your security domain) in the context of hash tables.  For hash tables, you have a hash function that generates a hash value from a key, and the hash value is generally folded/mapped on to the hash table buckets using `%` or `&` (the latter is faster if the bucket count is a multiple of 2).  Nothing to do with passwords here.

Comment: Looked at the link, this hash table implementation is less then ideal; if you want a constant hash table, recommend [gperf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/).